# Android studio Java update text in the loop

Tags: java, android, android-studio

first time learning coding language here..
I am struggling in many parts of Java, but I am slowly learning.

I was making an app and had to show dynamically updating text.
So the below code is my attempt, it works very well (sort of).
The problem is that it does not update the screen while program is running the for loop.

So when I press a button from main activity, it runs an activity called play.
It has 14 text fields of 0, and should update them to 7 one by one automatically.

But after running the code below, it just shows fourteen 7s after a moment. (no 0s to start with too!)
Any code for showing the screen so that I can put it under setText() ?

I am sorry if this question was asked before but I really couldn't find any answer online.

```
public class Play extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    Initialization();
}

public void Initialization() {
    TextView[] textViews = new TextView[] {
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_1),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_2),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_3),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_4),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_5),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_6),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_7),

            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_1),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_2),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_3),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_4),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_5),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_6),
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_7)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
            textViews[j].setText(Integer.toString(i));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you call `Thread.sleep(25)` on the UI thread. This means that the UI thread will be blocked and will not update your text views. After all that blocking, it is finally unblocked after the for loop, so you can immediately see all the text fields updating.

For better user experience, **never tell the UI thread to sleep.**

You need something that will do some work after an amount of time. `android.os.Handler` is a pretty good choice. It has a `postDelayed` method that will do the thing you want it to do after some time.

IMO, directly calling `postDelayed` can indeed do your job. But each `postDelayed` call contains another, in order to update the next text view after a few seconds. That means you'll end up with 14 layers of nesting! That's not very clean code, is it?

So, let me introduce the `Timer` class!

Here it is:

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

This thing is pretty cool.

To meet the requirements, let's add a `counter` and `textViewToUpdate` to your activity class so that we know what number is it and which text view to update next. Oh, and move that `textViews` variable to the class level:

```
int counter = 1;
int textViewToUpdate = 0;

TextView[] textViews;
```

And initialize the `textViews` in `onCreate`:

```
textViews = new TextView[] {
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_1),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_2),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_3),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_4),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_5),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_6),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1_7),

        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_1),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_2),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_3),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_4),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_5),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_6),
        (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2_7)
};
```

Create a timer in your class first:

```
Timer t;
```

In your `Initialization` method, create a runnable. This runnable is going to be run every a few seconds.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable () {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        PlayActivity self = PlayActivity.this;
        self.textViews[self.textViewToUpdate].setText(Integer.toString(self.counter));
        self.textViewToUpdate++;
        if (self.textViewToUpdate == self.textViews.length) {
            self.textViewToUpdate = 0;
            self.counter++;
            if (self.counter == 8) {
                self.t.stopTimer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, we create the timer and run it:

```
t = new Timer(r, interval, true);
```

You can replace `interval` with any number you like, maybe `250` (0.25 seconds)?

And BOOM! You did it!

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I am happy that I followed most of the code you wrote :) So amazed by how great people are in this website. One thing is.. my app crashes when move textViews to class level. I had to move it back to Initialization and make it final. I have no idea why it crashes though. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Seung Sorry! My bad! You should declare the `textViews` at class level but you should _initialize_ it in `onCreate`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot! It's 5:20 in the morning and still doing this! Thank god it's Saturday and coding is great fun :D

Comment: @seung  please help me guys. I want a program just like a countdown timer but it should be in the current thread.

Comment: @MuhammadArslan this is 5 years old thread. You should ask a new one!

Answer (score 0):

All of this happens way too fast for you to see. As you can easily calculate, **7x25ms = 175ms**, which passes really fast and you might not even notice the numbers changing on the screen.

I'd recommend you to increase the delay to, let's say **500ms** or something in that range so you might actually see the difference or changing the logic completely (you can for example use CountdownTimer with a Tick time of 500ms and change the text in `onTick` method, google it).

If it's just for testing purposes, why wouldn't you add a button and then call `Initialization` on that button's click? That way you can observe the values change starting from 0.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I wanted it to be quick, 14 textviews, 7 to go so 14 * 7 * 0.025= 2.45s. So whole thing is not so fast I guess. The thing is, it looks like the Initialization method is running before play activity is shown. When I press button that do the 'intent(main_activity.this, play.class)' thing, it waits for about 2.5s (setText time) and then show play activity with 7s.

I looked up countdowntimer, but I don't think that's what I need at the moment, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought too, it takes too long for it to come from 1 activity to the other. That's why I recommended that you put a simple button in the `Play` activity, so that you can control when the numbers will start changing. Do you understand my idea? Then you click it, and observe them change.